# Copy a Table in Vba Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table "TableEx" in a Sheet of my Excel File.
I have created a ListObject loTable and I have set it as follow:

```
'Define Variable
 sTableName = "TableEx"

'Define WorkSheet object
 Set oSheetName = Sheets("BBDD Ventas")

'Define Table Object
 Set loTable = oSheetName.ListObjects(sTableName)
```

The thing is that im trying to use some functions of tables  (for example .removeDuplicates)  but I
dont want that this actions could have effect in my real table (the one in the sheet).
When I run this line :

```
loTable.DataBodyRange.RemoveDuplicates
```

it remove the duplicates of my original table.
How can I do it?

Comment: You are still working with the table in the sheet. You could make a copy of the table and remove from that.

Comment: `loTable` is not a copy of your table, it's just a reference to it.

Comment: Thanks Tim. How could I make a copy of table?

Comment: What other functions (except `.removeDuplicates`) are you going to use? What are you going to do with the new table (data)? Where do you want to put it? In another worksheet or in the same worksheet starting from e.g. cell `Z1`. Please do clarify.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Mostly .removeduplicates. I am doing that but I am doing it with a loop process and its a little anoying. I just want to know if I could have table as an object that could be a copy of a real table in the workbook, and apply the methods that this kind of object provides.